# Reverse-Proxy fails

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, jboss, wildfly8

I have Apache and Wildfly installed on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 Server and I created a Reverse-Proxy, so that Apache proxies Wildfly. It works, but only half of it. If I hit `http://myserver/wildfly/myprogram/index.xthml` I do get the entry page, but the links are not adapted properly. Links and image sources ignore the `http://myserver`**/wildfly**`/myprogram/` entry and are like this: `http://myserver/myprogram/`. I believe there must be a missing part in my configuration. I added the following lines into the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /wildfly http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /wildfly http://localhost:8080
```

How can I tell Apache to include `/wildfly` into all the links, basically using links that work?